# Access remote directory in shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a shell script that accepts directory inputs. One of the directories I want to process is at a remote location. I am able to ssh into the remote host but I want to be able to reference the remote directory in a similar manner as a UNC path on Windows (in Windows you can type "\[remote host][share]" and reference that path in batch files). Is there a clean way to do a similar thing with ssh on Unix? When I call the shell script, I want to be able to type something like:

```
./run_shell_script.sh ssh://<host>/<path>
```

instead of running extra commands just to process that one directory? This is being done on a list of directories in a loop, so I don't want to have special code for remote directories.

Comment: What does your script do?

Comment: Well essentially it ends up calling a Perl script that accepts directory inputs. It parses log files and generates a report about them.

Comment: the directory has log files in it? im asking to know if it's a valid thing what you what, sound weird to me and maybe there is another solution

Comment: Yes it has log files.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to parse the URI like this:

```
_uri=ssh://host/path/to/file
_host=`echo $_uri | sed 's|^ssh://\([^/]*\)/.*$|\1|'`
_dir=`echo $_uri | sed "s|^ssh://$_host/\(.*\)\$|\1|"`
```

and then just to use these variables to ssh:

```
scp $_host:$_dir $local_dir
```

Also, [`sshfs`](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) may be interesting for you: it allows to mount a remote host into a directory on the local machine without the NFS administration burden and even root privileges.